# Can Azure metrics logging frequency/collection period be changed?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, metrics

Per [Azure documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-metrics#what-are-the-characteristics-of-metrics):
All metrics have one-minute frequency (unless specified otherwise in a metric's definition).

Also, at least for VM guest metrics, when enabled the metrics are stored in an Azure Storage Table that aggregates 10 days of metrics, either at the minute or hour level. That's mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071394/how-storage-api-can-be-used-to-get-azure-classic-vm-metrics).

Can either the metric frequency or the collection period for each table be controlled by users?
For example, could we get metrics at 5-minute or 15-minute intervals, or restrict the table to 2 days or 5 days of metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the frequency of collection for your guest os metrics.

By default they are set to 60 seconds, but they can be adjusted to any number of seconds between 1 and 315360000 (which if my math doesn't fail me, should be 10 years).

You can change this by going to your virtual machine in the Portal and clicking on the Diagnostics Settings.  There you'll see: Overview, Performance counters, Logs, Crash dumps, Sinks, Agent.  You'll need to click on Performance counters, and on that tab change from basic to custom in order to specify your collection frequencies.

Here is a gif of the above steps: [The Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzzxW.gif)

As for the retention period, this is also changeable.  You'll need to make the change to the actual table storing the diagnostics.  You can use the REST API to get your tables properties: [Get Em Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-table-service-properties) and set them: [Set Em Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-table-service-properties).

You'll need to set the RetentionPolicy/Days value to your desired duration.  This can range from 1 day to 365 (a year).